# Localstack S3 + AWS Java SDK keeps erroring with inexistent Key ID

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, localstack, aws-sdk-java-2.0

While this question has been asked multiple times, none of the answers I came across seem to make any difference in my case... (Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758521/localstack-docker-compose-s3) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225305/aws-sdk-for-java-s3-bucket-access-key-id-issue))

I'm using the latest Java SDK (0.21.11 as of writing this) but no matter what I do, I keep running into the `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` error..

So, I'm running localstack to provide S3 "emulation" to a Java Spring Service. Both of them run on Docker, via docker compose:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "localstack"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      # - LOCALSTACK_HOST=host.docker.internal:4566
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=localstack
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=localstack
      - DEBUG=1
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "./init/init-aws.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh" # ready hook
      - "./volume:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

  docrenderer:
    image: myapp/docrenderer
    container_name: docrenderer
    ports:
      - "8010:8080" # ssh -R 80:localhost:8009 localhost.run
      - "5010:5005"
    environment:
      - AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=localstack
      - AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET=localstack
      - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=*:5005,suspend=n
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=default,local,aws
      - IMAGE_STORAGE_BASE_PATH=image/thumbnail
      - IMAGE_STORAGE_BUCKET=example-bucket
      # Replace with base64 encoded google storage service account key (json). See GCP IAM.
      - STORAGE_GOOGLE_CLOUD_CREDENTIALS=ewog(...)Cn0K # dummy-key (base64 encoded)
      - EMULATOR_PUBSUB_URL=pubsub:8681
      - EMULATOR_PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=project-dev
    depends_on:
      pubsub:
        condition: service_healthy
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
```

I clearly set the credentials as `localstack` (I tried just `test` before) on the `localstack` container and then do the same thing to setup the `docrenderer` spring stuff (which reads the values from env variables and sets them on the `application.yml` file)

When starting `localstack` I create the bucket I intend to use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
awslocal s3 mb s3://example-bucket
```

Then, on my code, I use the `S3AsyncClient` with the [CRT-based client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/crt-based-s3-client.html), using the `crtBuilder()` method, with code that looks like this:

```java
public class AwsS3Configuration {

  public static final Region DEFAULT_AWS_REGION = Region.EU_CENTRAL_1;
  // public static final String AWS_S3_BASE_URL = "s3." + DEFAULT_AWS_REGION.id() + ".amazonaws.com/";
  public static final String AWS_S3_BASE_URL = "s3." + DEFAULT_AWS_REGION.id() + ".localstack:4566";
  // public static final String AWS_ENDPOINT_URI = "http://host.docker.internal:4566";
  @Bean
  public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider(AwsS3Properties awsS3Properties) {
    return StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
        AwsBasicCredentials.create(awsS3Properties.getAccessKeyId(), awsS3Properties.getSecretAccessKey()));
  }

  @Bean
  public S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
    return S3AsyncClient.crtBuilder()
        .region(DEFAULT_AWS_REGION)
        .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
        //.endpointOverride(URI.create(AWS_ENDPOINT_URI))
        .build();
  }

  (...)
}
```

As you can see, I also tried using the endpoint override, but no matter what I do, I keep hitting the `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` error..

What am I doing wrong??? I don't see anything that would jump out as poorly configured, according to the [Configuration page](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/configuration/)

I also tried using Commandeer to browse/inspect the localstack instance, and it doesn't show me any buckets, though it DOES connect to localstack with those credentials and.

If I ask `localstack` itself to list the buckets, then it will reply that the bucket exists (and is empty):

```bash
root@231b6fd8e215:/opt/code/localstack# awslocal s3api list-buckets
{
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "Name": "example-bucket",
            "CreationDate": "2023-10-31T14:13:16Z"
        }
    ],
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "webfile",
        "ID": "75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a"
    }
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!